# Cannot read value form <selected> element with JQuery/Javascript

Tags: jquery, forms, select, element

I cannot get the value of a form  element, even though from other similar questions this is supposed to work.

FYI - I have a function that writes 2 id's (#selected_sign & #selected_sign_form) to an article and a form nested in the article - this is purely for styling/identification purposes.

Here is the function that fails to get the element value based on the assigned IDs:

```
var sSize_prices= new Array();
sSize_prices["45"]=45; //per sq ft
sSize_prices["60"]=65; //per sq ft

function getSizePrice() {
var getSizePrice=0;

var theForm = document.forms["selected_sign_form"];
var selectedSize = theForm.elements["os0"];
alert(selectedSize.value);

getSizePrice = sSize_prices[selectedSize.value];

return getSizePrice;
}
```

Here is the HTML markup containing the ID'd article and form:

```
<section class="sign_type">
    <h3>Selection</h3>
    <article class="signs" onclick="calculateTotal()" id="selected_sign">
      <figure class="sample">
        <a href="/cat/s1b.png" rel="lightbox" title="Sign preview">
          <img class="sign_preview" src="/cat/s1.png" alt="Sign preview" title="Sign preview" />
        </a>
      </figure>
      <form action="" class="options" onsubmit="return false;" id="selected_sign_form">
        <div class="sign_option1"><label class="on0">Size:</label>
          <select name="Size" class="os0" onclick="calculateTotal()">
            <option value="45">45cm sq</option>
            <option value="60">60cm sq</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="sign_option2"><label class="on1">Qty:</label>
          <input name="Quantity" class="os1" value="1" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" />
        </div>
        <div class="sign_option3"><label class="on2">Fine:</label>
          <input name="Custom" class="os2" value="" />
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="price"></div>
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't think you can assign array values like this: `sSize_prices["45"]=45;`. In JavaScript you can only access array-index by number. If you want it the way you have now, you need to use an [**Object**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

Comment: That is purely to check the <selected> value against the array to find the corresponding 'price'. It works very well, especially for large option arrays with different pricing for each option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, just needs a small HTML amending.

The following line is looking for an element inside your form, with the attribute "name" that equals "os0":

```
theForm.elements["os0"];
```

If you'll set the name of your "select" tag to "os0" - it will work.

**E.G.**

```
<select name="os0" class="os0" onclick="calculateTotal()">
```

Comment: This works perfectly, too, and is even more efficient a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using jQuery. You can use different [jQuery Selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), use 'id'  selector to get form element and use `.find()` to get select element.

```
var sSize_prices= new Array();
sSize_prices["45"]=45; //per sq ft
sSize_prices["60"]=65; //per sq ft

function getSizePrice() {
var getSizePrice=0;

var selectBox= $("#selected_sign_form").find(".os0:first");
alert($(selectBox).val());

getSizePrice = sSize_prices[$(selectBox).val()];

return getSizePrice;
}
```

**NOTE** - please include jquery library before above `script`. To include jquery library see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp)